# getting exceptions when using both caffeine caching and simple caching in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache, caffeine-cache

i am new to springboot and trying to implement both caffeine caching and simple caching based on a requirement.

if i use any one them its compiling and working fine but using together in same class or different class i am getting exceptions.

is it okay to use both caching mechanisms?

**Exceptions:**

```
Oct 10, 2023 9:40:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='6525775bd54ff65387d86e72', description='null'}-localhost:27017] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:109)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:131)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:647)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:512)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:355)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receive(InternalStreamConnection.java:315)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:215)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Oct 10, 2023 9:40:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-rtt-ClusterId{value='6525775bd54ff65387d86e72', description='null'}-localhost:27017] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:435)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.access$1300(DefaultServerMonitor.java:57)
 com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$RoundTripTimeRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:409)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

**Java Class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {


    @Bean
    public CacheManager caffeineCacheManager() {
        CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(Arrays.asList("task1"));
        cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder());
        return cacheManager;
    }

    Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineCacheBuilder() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.DAYS) // Set TTL for 30 Days
                .maximumSize(5000); // Set maximum size to 5000 entries
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("task2")));
        return cacheManager;
    }

}
```

**maven library;**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: i am getting exceptions only if i use both cache mechanisms and if i use any one of them they are working as expected

Thanks

Comment: That is not an exception but a warning/ However why use 2 caching mechanism why not stick with just caffeine as that is a proper cache whilst a map isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum caffeine is new implementation and simple cache is existing one which is already in production build. so i don't want to break anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//imports

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CompositeCacheManager cacheManager = new CompositeCacheManager();
        List<CacheManager> cacheManagers = Arrays.asList(caffeineCacheManager(), concurrentMapCacheManager());
        cacheManager.setCacheManagers(cacheManagers);
        return cacheManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public CacheManager caffeineCacheManager() {
        CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        //add new cache here by separating with comma.
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(Arrays.asList("task1"));
        cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder());
        return cacheManager;
    }
    Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineCacheBuilder() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.DAYS) // Set TTL for 30 Days
                .maximumSize(5000); // Set maximum size to 5000 entries
    }
    @Bean
    public CacheManager concurrentMapCacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("task2")));
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).